# Multiple UVmaps, but only rendering one

Tags: uv

I'm still working on my Lego project and I want to add Eyes and Mouth to the character. But somehow only the Eyes are being rendered. 
I've already watched a lot of tutorials where they showed me a few different ways to get to this.

[image: So my Mouth is rendered purple.]

I hope you can help me with this Problem because I can't move forward wihtout it.

Thanks a lot.
Greetings

W.Zayde

Comment: This purple color indicates that the texture is missing. Have a look at the corresponding node or at the texture itself in the UV/image editor

Comment: Thanks for the tipp, but I am new in Blender, so could you describe it a little bit more what I have to change. Because I just went to the Image Texture, but I realised I'm a but overwhelmed.

Comment: read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-a-transparent-image-on-top-of-a-material/46447#46447